# Why I'm getting empty string at the beginning scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm a new scraper and using Scrapy and I'm trying to scrape data from this table but I'm trying to get all countries first but it's working but I'm facing or getting empty string first. Please have a look this code and help me please if you can. Thank you.

```
import scrapy


class Covid19Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'covid19'
    allowed_domains = ['worldometers.info']
    start_urls = ['https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/']

    def parse(self, response):
        table = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "table table-bordered")]')[0]
        trs = table.xpath('.//tr')[3:]
        for tr in trs:
            country = tr.xpath('.//td[2]//a//text()|'
                               './/td[2]//text()').extract_first().strip()

            yield {
                "Country": country,
            }
```

Error I'm receiving is below

```
{'Country': ''}
2020-09-20 23:01:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/>
{'Country': ''}
2020-09-20 23:01:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/>
{'Country': ''}
2020-09-20 23:01:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/>
{'Country': ''}
2020-09-20 23:01:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/>
{'Country': ''}
2020-09-20 23:01:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/>
{'Country': 'World'}
2020-09-20 23:01:18 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/>
{'Country': 'USA'}
```

Comment: Can you give us an example of a country that has leading newlines?

Comment: Hello @PaulM. thanks for the notice. Apologize, I'm facing empty string as you can see on the error files that I shared. Showing empty at the beginning.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now. Sorry, I'll take another look.

Comment: Have you tried changing the `3` in `trs = table.xpath('.//tr')[3:]` around to different values? It seems like the first five `tr` tags don't contain any country information, and you'll want to skip those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221791/discussion-between-macaw-and-paul-m).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @PaulM make the point I change the row number. I set 9 instead of 3 and it's working fine now. Here is a solution

```
import scrapy


class Covid19Spider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'covid19'
    allowed_domains = ['worldometers.info']
    start_urls = ['https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/']

    def parse(self, response):
        table = response.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "table table-bordered")]')[0]
        trs = table.xpath('.//tr')[9:] # Set 9 instead of 3
        for tr in trs:
            country = tr.xpath('.//td[2]//a//text()|'
                               './/td[2]//text()').extract_first().strip()

            yield {
                "Country": country,
            }
```